# Why is there different output when multiplying with doubles?

Tags: c#, double

Let's say I have the following:

```
double f;
double c = 5;

Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", c, f = 9 / 5 * c + 32);
```

Which will give the output: `5 | 37`

Meanwhile:

```
double f;
double c = 5;

Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", c, f = 9.0 / 5.0 * c + 32);
```

Will give the correct output: `5 | 41` (Representing how much 5 degrees Celsius is in Farenheit)

I know that I am working with a double, but I lack the insight into why both outcomes aren't equivalent with each other?

Comment: Search for integer division in C#.

Comment: Arghh. Read about **integer division**

Comment: Why soo upset? I'm sorry for my question.

Comment: @htmlNewbie, I'm perplexed by the aggression your question has invoked. It seems a perfectly sensible one to me. Please don't let this bad experience put you off from asking future questions.

Comment: @DavidArno Thank you David, for that comment and for your answer to my question. I have had some bad experiences asking questions before, but i thought that i had improved my question-asking-skill by now... Still some work to do i guess. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the C language was designed [essentially] as a hardware-agnostic assembly language. Consequently, division, unless it involves a floating point value is integer division, the a CPU will do it in a single instruction. That means that an expression like:

```
int x = 9 ;
int y = 5 ;
int z = x / y ;
```

That will usually compile down to a single machine instruction (possibly with others to load/store values to/from registers, the net result of which is a quotient and a remainder. So, the above `int z = x / y` will resolve to **`1`**, leaving the remainder of `4` on the table (note that if you want the remainder, use the `%` operator: `int z = x % y` yields the expected `4`.

If one of the operands is a floating point value, then floating point division is used (much expensive, computationally speaking).

Since C# inherits from that legacy, it behaves in the same way. So, §14.7.2 of the Standard says

> **14.7.2 Division operator**
>
> For an operation of the form `x / y`, binary operator overload resolution (§14.2.4) is applied
>   to select a specific operator implementation. The operands are converted to the parameter types
>   of the selected operator, and the type of the result is the return type of the operator.
>
> The predefined division operators are listed below.
>   The operators all compute the quotient of `x` and `y`.
>
> - Integer division:
>
>   ```
>   int   operator /( int   x, int   y );
>   uint  operator /( uint  x, uint  y );
>   long  operator /( long  x, long  y );
>   ulong operator /( ulong x, ulong y );
>   void  operator /( long  x, ulong y );
>   void  operator /( ulong x, long  y );
>   ```
>
> The operators with `void` return type always produce a compile-time error. Consequently,
>   it is an error for one operand to be of type `long` and the other to be of type `ulong`.
>
> If the value of the right operand is zero, a `System.DivideByZeroException` is thrown.
>
> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of the result is
>   the largest possible integer that is less than the absolute value of the quotient of
>   the two operands. The result is zero or positive when the two operands have the same
>   sign and zero or negative when the two operands have opposite signs.
>
> If the left operand is the smallest `int` or `long` value (−2<sup>31</sup> or −2<sup>63</sup>,
>   respectively) and the right operand is `–1`, an overflow occurs. In a `checked` context, this
>   causes a `System.ArithmeticException` (or a subclass thereof) to be thrown. In an `unchecked`
>   context, it is implementation-defined as to whether a `System.ArithmeticException` (or a
>   subclass thereof) is thrown or the overflow goes unreported with the resulting value being that
>   of the left operand.
>
> [*discussion of floating-point and decimal division elided*]

That's why.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the integer syntax (9 and not 9.0), each operations was rounded without decimal

Comment: It's not really rounded but truncated.  Someone may infer that `9/5` would yield `2` if it were rounding.